# <import/> statements in Spring MVC

Tags: java, xml, spring, model-view-controller, servlets

If I have a statement in my servlet.xml like this:

```
<import resource="classes/com/au/curtin/example.xml/>
```

and an example.xml at that directory location that has Spring bean definitions as well as things like `<component:context-scan/>` and `<tx:annotation-driven/>`. Are these statements imported along with the bean definitions into the servlet.xml context or do I need to include duplicate `<component:context-scan/>` in my servlet.xml file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main purpose of import is to avoid duplication. With import the file is completely imported.Everything including bean defination and other configurations are copied.

Comment: Beautiful, you are a gentleman and a scholar sir. Many thanks